# How to get next day from specified date in android?

Tags: android, date

I have different dates in my program like 08-Mar-2017. How can I get next or previous date from this specified date?

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setDate(your date);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

You have to convert the string into date and set it to calendar and then you can add a day and to remove

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```